# Mongoose - ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "states"

Tags: mongoose

I am receiving a cast error to ObjectId and I really cannot see why:

***CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "states"***

> ```
>   var data = require('../../../data/seed/refs/countries/countries.json');
>     model.Super_CountryRefs.find({}).exec(function (err, collection) {
>         if (collection.length === 0) {
>             data.forEach(function (country) {
>                 var countryModel = new model.Super_CountryRefs;
>                 var country_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
>                 countryModel._id = country_id;
>                 countryModel.name = country.name;
>                 countryModel.abbr = country.abbr;
>                 countryModel.code = country.code;
>                 countryModel.flag = country.flag;
>                 if(country.states != undefined){
>                     if(country.states.length > 0){
>                         country.states.forEach(function(state){
>                             console.log('State: ' + state.name)
>                             var stateModel = new model.Super_StateProvinceRefs;
>                             stateModel.name = state.name;
>                             stateModel.abbr = state.abbr;
> EXCEPTION BEING THROWN HERE --> stateModel.country = countryModel._id;
>                             stateModel.save(function(err){
>                                 if(err){
>                                     console.log('Error: ' + err)
>                                 } else {
>                                     countryModel.states.push(state)
>                                 }
>                             })
>                         })
>                     }
>                 }
>
>                 countryModel.save(function(err){
>                     if(err)
>                         console.log('Error: ' + err);
>                 })
>             })
>             console.log('Country/State Seed Complete');
>         }
>     });
> ```

**My States Model:**

```
        country: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SuperCountry',
        required: 'Country is required'
    }
```

**My Country Model:**

```
    states : [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SuperStateProvinceRefs'
}]
```

To make matters more strange, the data is populated, and correctly, in the database. Can anyone see why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this was not the error:

```
    stateModel.country = countryModel._id;
```

This was the error:

```
   countryModel.states.push(state)
```

I was pushing the whole state object when country's schema had ObjectId ref for state.

This is the correct answer:

```
    countryModel.states.push(state._id)
```